# error itms-90161 after changing version

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, itunes, provisioning-profile, application-loader

First of all, this is what I currently get:

> error itms-90161: "Invalid Provisioning Profile. The provisioning
>   profile included in the bundle be.x.x [Payload/x.app] is invalid.
>   [Missing code-signing certificate]. A Distributiion Provisioning
>   profile should be used when submitting apps to the App Store. For more
>   information, visit the iOS Developer Portal.

I got this error message before I created the corresponging version in `itunnesconnect.apple.com`. After I created the correct version, I could upload my app using `Application Loader 3.0.`

When my new version was in status "waiting for review", I had to create a newer version. In order to do this, *(according to the message I got in the website)* I had to cancel the version which was waiting for review. I cancelled it and changed its version to the newer version.

And now, although the version I send and the version whose status is "prepare for submission" in the website, are the same, I still get this error. But I'm pretty sure that there is no any issue with the provisioning profile and so.

How can I solve this? Was there better way for my case (deleting waiting version and uploading instead newer version)?

Comment: Did you sign the new build with a distribution certificate?  By the error message, it looks like it may have been signed with a developer cert / profile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although it is not a directly answer for my question, I solved it:

I just switched from the program `Application Loader` to the latest version of `Xcode`. The problem probably comes from the way Application Loader connects to `tunnesconnect.apple.com` because I didn't change anything in my project and just created a new `archive` using `Xcode` and it is succeeded to upload it properly to my account.

Also: *deleting waiting version and uploading instead newer version* is currently the only way to do that according to the messages appeared in `tunnesconnect.apple.com`